# Order by date in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, date

I'm making a simple table in SQLite which I would like to order by descending date. Here's the SQL I'm running to generate the table:

```
create table projects("project_creation_date" text);
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ("08/05/2019");
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ("05/12/2018");
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ("06/08/2015");
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ("01/01/2020");
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ("02/03/2020");
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ("02/03/2019");
```

Here's my select statement:

```
select "project_creation_date" from projects order by strftime("project_creation_date", '%d/%m/%Y') desc;
```

This is still not ordering my dates properly:

```
08/05/2019
05/12/2018
06/08/2015
01/01/2020
02/03/2020
02/03/2019
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first argument of 'strtime' function is format ;)

Comment: Switching the arguments around still produces the same result....

Comment: Why the downvotes? What could possibly be wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to stop inserting non ISO-compliant date literals into your SQLite tables.  *Always* use an ISO-style date, which will sort properly:

```
create table projects("project_creation_date" text);
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ('2019-05-08');
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ('2018-12-05');
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ('2015-08-06');
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ('2020-01-01');
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ('2020-03-02');
insert into projects ("project_creation_date") values ('2019-03-02');
```

Note that on other databases, such as Oracle, your insert statements would have failed completely, the original strings not even being recognized as date literals.  It is a quirk of SQLite, which does not actually have a formal date type, only a date *affinity*, that dates are stored as text.  Hence, it is important to also use a proper format if you care about things like sorting.

If you *must* stick with your current design, then you will need some ugly SQL code to get the ordering you want.  SQLite does not have an `strptime` or other similar text to date function, so you will have to piece together the date in the right order while sorting:

```
SELECT project_creation_date
FROM projects
ORDER BY
    SUBSTR(project_creation_date, 7, 4) ||
    SUBSTR(project_creation_date, 4, 2) ||
    SUBSTR(project_creation_date, 1, 2);
```

Again, take a look at what you have to do to make your current data model work, and consider whether changing the date format might be worth it.

Comment: What if my dataset already contains non ISO-compliant date literals? What if I have a custom date format I want to use? Isn't that what `strftime` is for as explained in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html?

Comment: If you are absolutely forced to stick with your current design, then yes, you might have to use something like `strftime` to first convert your non standard dates to a proper format, before sorting.  But you should seriously consider changing the way you store your dates; it will make your life much easier.

Comment: that's kind of what I'm looking for here and why I thought `strftime` was appropriate. Is there an alternative solution which either 1) first converts the dates to ISO-style date then sorts by descending order or 2) uses `strftime` to directly order the dates in descending order?

Comment: @user32882 No, `strftime` _won't_ work here, because that function _starts_ with a valid date, and then generates a _string_ as output.  You need the opposite direction, namely starting with a _string_ and generating a date.  Consider my updated answer, which is one way to do this.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I just want to be able to run my script directly on an automatic excel export of the data and have the script handle all anomalies. The exports contains dates in that format. The alternative approach you propose seems to be missing an `asc` or `desc` keyword. Would you add that so I can accept it? Thanks...

Comment: @user32882 Then you have some other problem, because my second query definitely sorts the way you want, [see this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7ca00479720bac4ceb6d1c30705b6dfc).  Maybe some other problem with your data?

Comment: I think you were missing an `asc` or `desc` keyword... please see my last comment...

Comment: You may sort ascending or descending, it is up to you, this isn't the crux of my answer (or the problem) in any case.